# Cordova - PluginResult cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I created a small Cordova Plugin added it to my test app.
In plugin.xml I set min cordova version to 3.4.0:

```
  <engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.4.0"/>
  </engines>
```

In my plugin JAVA class I import the PluginResult package:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
```

And I create a "PluginResult" object:

```
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
```

When I build the app I get the error that not found symbol:

**error: cannot find symbol PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);**

**error: package PluginResult does not exist**

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be hard to locate the error when you don't post the full source code.

Anyway, the plugin structure requires so many files that your best approach to create a plugin is to use a sample plugin as base.

Check out the **[cordova-plugin-hello](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello)** sample, you can download it and start editing everything accordingly to your needs.

After installing the sample plugin, test it by adding this code to your app:

```
var success = function(message) {
    alert(message);
}

var failure = function() {
    alert("Error calling Hello Plugin");
}

hello.greet("World", success, failure);
```

Then, everytime you make a change to the plugin, uninstall and reinstall it into your app to ensure your changes have worked.

Comment: Sorry, I found my mistake ... It's missing an import line:

import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake ... It's missing an import line:

```
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
```